# timeline view in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

what is the problem is not able to set box line height according to card the circular checked image should by in center

I tried the following:

```kotlin
val sampleTimelineData = listOf(
        TimelineEvent(iconResourceId = R.drawable.ic_check_blue, title = "Address ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg", time="250 pts",isBirthdayFilled=false),
        TimelineEvent(iconResourceId = R.drawable.ic_check_blue, title = "E-mail", time="250 pts",isBirthdayFilled=false),
        TimelineEvent(iconResourceId = R.drawable.ic_check_blue, title = "Gender Info", time="250 pts",isBirthdayFilled=true),
        TimelineEvent(iconResourceId = R.drawable.ic_check_blue, title = "Annual Income", time="250 pts",isBirthdayFilled=true),
)

// Sample data for demonstration
val demoInsightTimelineData = listOf(
        InsightListTimeline(iconResourceId = R.drawable.ic_check_blue, title = "Link Plaid Account", time="250 pts",isBirthdayFilled=false),
        InsightListTimeline(iconResourceId = R.drawable.ic_check_blue, title = "View First Insight", time="250 pts",isBirthdayFilled=true),
       )

@Composable
fun DisplayInsightVerticalTimeline(events: List<InsightListTimeline>,isBirthdayFilled: Boolean) {
    val dotColor = if (isBirthdayFilled) White else ActiveBlue500

    Row (modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = spacing_16dp)){
        Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = spacing_24dp, bottom = spacing_24dp)
                        .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {
            // Loop through the list of TimelineEvents
            events.forEachIndexed { index, event ->
                // Circular dot representing an event
                Box(
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(spacing_2dp)
                                .border(spacing_1dp, color = Silver500, shape = CircleShape)
                                .size(spacing_20dp)
                                .clip(shape = CircleShape)
                ) {
                    if (event.isBirthdayFilled)
                        DisplayBaseIcons(resourceIconId = event.iconResourceId, color=White, modifier = Modifier.background(dotColor))
                }

                // Connecting vertical line between dots
                if (index < events.size - 1) {
                    Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                    .height(spacing_55dp)
                                    .background(Silver500)
                                    .width(spacing_1dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        CommonSpacer(width = spacing_24dp)

        Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp, Alignment.Start)
        ) {
            // Second Column
            Column(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp, Alignment.Top),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            ) {
                // Loop through the list of TimelineEvents
                events.forEach { event ->
                    BackGroundCardMedium {
                        RewardJourneyLayerOne(
                                messageOne = event.title,
                                messageThree = event.time
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```